# How long would it take to develop something similar to a Kernel from scratch?

Tags: kernel

I want to build a software similar to a Kernel, how long would it take me and which languages should I be learning.
In it's essence I want to know which is the prior knowledge one would need to program something of the sort.

Comment: you should probably at least specify which OS you are referring to.

Comment: In my school time a "kernel" is implementing Operating System running on Hardware Devices. C is the definite choice.

Comment: and you wont get far without assembler. good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you want to manage "user processes".

Switching between processes requires getting down and dirty with your processor - using interrupts from the clock or being triggered by another user process making a blocking system call.

When you switch processes you have to save the processor state as it was when in the middle of the user's process. That involves **assembly**. There's no two ways about it.

Once you have process switching then you can have fun managing a system API, priority queues, memory management, etc, etc.

Because assembly is involved and you'll want to make use of the most efficient structures you can you'll probably want to code largely in C (which is just a macro assembler, truth be told).